# I need to find the min and max rates from a file and cannot get the min to work correctly, does anyone see my error?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find the min and max rate in this file. I have the max figured out but cannot resolve the min. Does anyone have any suggestions to what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/bash
  2 echo "Starting"
  3 FILE="/var/www/html/bitcoin.txt"
  4 COUNT=0
  5 MAX=0
  6 MIN=""
  7 LAST=0
  8 PREV=""
  9 while read line
 10 do
 11     COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
 12     RATE=$( echo "$line" | jq . )
 13     if [[ $RATE > $LAST ]]
 14     then
 15         LAST=$RATE
 16         MAX=$LAST
 17     fi
 18
 19     if [[ $PREV < $RATE ]]
 20     then
 21         PREV=$RATE
 22         MIN=$PREV
 23     fi
 24
 25 done < $FILE
 26 echo "maximum: "
 27 echo "The max is $MAX"
 28 echo "minimum: "
 29 echo "The min is $MIN"
 30 echo "Finished!"
 31
 32 # the max is correct, gives max of 59181.2048
 33 # min is stuck on 0?
```

Comment: the `if` statements are both the same because you reversed the order of the variables

Comment: put $RATE first in both comparisons ... that way it reads as spoken `if RATE is larger than LAST` and `if RATE is smaller than PREV`

Comment: IMHO a shell loop isn't the right tool especially if your input is JSON, however another issue is that inside a bash `[[ ... ]]` test, `>` and `<` are *lexicographical* comparison operators - if you want numeric comparison, use `-gt` and `-lt`, or use `(( ... ))` instead for numeric evaluation

Comment: Also, it's not actually an error but you don't need the $LAST and $PREV variables, they're just duplicates of $MAX and $MIN.